# php pull field with variable+string

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to pull up a field in the database using a string and a variable.

currently the field im trying to pull from the db is '28price'.

My current code is this

```
$price = $cart['amount'];
$string = 'price';
var_dump($fetch[$price."".$string]);
```

full code can be viewed at pastebin ==> https://pastebin.com/LM1ecp13

I can't seem to figure out how to work it right. The error it returns with is...

"Notice: Undefined index: 28price in C:\xampp\htdocs\misc\cart.php on line 15
NULL"

I assure you guys the field does exist and if i call it manually with $fetch['28price'] it works fine.

picture of DB ==> https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxSd7.jpg

Comment: this is really easy if you put your mind to it; concatenate but just not the way you're doing it now.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ? His code should work he's concatenating correctly https://3v4l.org/bs7T0 Not sure what you mean..

Comment: Make a var_dump of $fetch to verify whether that actually contains what you think ...

Comment: im aware that i need to concatenante but i must be getting the syntax wrong because it isnt getting parsed right. What is the answer to this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it isnt getting parsed right"? So what _exact_ error message _do_ you get?

Comment: i echoed the price, it correctly outputs 28.

Comment: output error ==> 
Notice: Undefined index: 28price in C:\xampp\htdocs\misc\cart.php on line 14

Comment: @BTCDude then please `var_dump($fetch);` and actually see if you can ctrl+f and locate "28price" and confirm it's actually a top level key.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index` that means there's no key called "28price"

Comment: OK, an "undefined index" is something different than a "parse error", isn't it? Most likely `$fetch` does not contain an element with key `28price`, that's all.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: 28price in C:\xampp\htdocs\misc\cart.php on line 14
NULL is what i get for var_dump($fetch[$price.'price']);

Comment: im looking at the database @IsThisJavascript its there.

Comment: Look at the contents of your variable `$fetch`, that is where your issue is, not inside that database.

Comment: @BTCDude so... that (wiki) answer below; does it work or not? your post at this point is unclear.

Comment: @BTCDude PHP thinks otherwise and I'm with PHP on this one. Dump your `$fetch` array and see if you can locate it as a key.

Comment: var_dump($fetch[$price."".$string]); returned with Notice: Undefined index: 28price in C:\xampp\htdocs\misc\cart.php on line 15
NULL $string = 'price; and price is 28

Comment: main post updated.

Comment: included screenie of database to show the field is indeed there and with a value.

Comment: @BTCDude Could we take a look at the key then from the output of `var_dump`? I'm suspecting you've maybe got a white space at the end of the name or you've completely missed it from your query call. Either way PHP believes it cannot locate it, your original  code should have worked like I showed in my comment at the start of this thread

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LM1ecp13

Comment: @BTCDude I don't know how many times I have to tell you, but running `var_dump($fetch);` will tell you that you do not have the key called "28price". Look at what you are pulling from the database with your query;  `$fetch = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id, name, price FROM stock WHERE id='$cart[wid]'"));` you are selecting `id, name, price` the solution here is to add `,28price` to your select...

Comment: You code is servery  at risk of MySQL injection attacks, expecially the code within your `case "delete":` please switch over to using [prepared statments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) as that code is not suitable for production environment

Comment: im facepalming so hard. I am ashamed that i have wasted all of your time. I bring dishonour to my family. I did not think of the key the same one you were thinking. Please post this answer so i can credit you.

Comment: @BTCDude it's ok dude lol. Just remember for next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context: OP posted his code within the comments; https://pastebin.com/LM1ecp13

Solution:
This line;
`$fetch = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id, name, price FROM stock WHERE id='$cart[wid]'"));`
Is the problem. You are selecting `id, name, price` but you are missing `28price` hence why you are getting the undefined index error...

Your query should be `"SELECT id, name, price, 28price FROM stock WHERE id='$cart[wid]'"`

Comment: Thank you, i cant believe i missed such an obvious error. I also changed it to mysqli_prepare();